# Find a basis for the subspace $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\lbrace f \in P_n(\mathbb{R}) |f(a) = 0\rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the subspace of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\lbrace f \in P_n(\mathbb{R}) |f(a) = 0\rbrace$, where $a$ is a fixed real number.

From the definition

$f(x)=c_0x^n+c_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_n$ and  $f(a)=0$ means  $$a^nc_0+a^{n-1}c_1+\cdots+c_n=0$$

I understand this is a system of one homogeneous linear equation in the $n+1$ unknowns $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_n$. But how do I proceed to find a basis for the subspace of this equation?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $f$ satisfies $f(a) = 0$ if and only if $x - a$ is a factor of $f$; that is, $f$ lies in your set if and only if there exists a $g \in P_{n - 1}(\mathbb{R})$ for which

$$f(x) = (x - a) g(x)$$

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to find the basis. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @user59036 This allows us to relate the vector space back to $P_{n - 1}$; to be explicit, if we choose a basis of $P_{n - 1}$ and multiply each basis vector by $x - a$, we get the desired basis.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly express the basis?

Comment: @user59036 Sure: Do you know (i.e. the standard one) a basis for $P_{n - 1}$?

Comment: A monomial basis: $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots,x^{n-1}\}$ ??

Comment: @user59036 Yep. So $\{x - a, x(x - a), x^2(x - a), ..., x^{n - 1} (x - a)\}$ works.